# Anchor/Dock to position DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, anchor, docking

I am trying to figure out how to position my DataGridView correctly inside of the parent container, but despite trying widths/heights/docks/anchors/etc. I absolutely cannot figure this out.

- I would like to have the table anchored to the left/right/bottom but have some padding to keep it from being flush against the sides/bottom.
- I want to keep some extra space at the top as I plan to put a second container there with additional options.
- Not sure if this is related, but I would like the rows to be a percentage of the DataGridView's width. Can this be done?

How can I achieve this? I currently have the following set, but as can be seen from the screenshot, it only seems to anchor to the left and for some reason stays near the top.

```
    dgv.Width = parent.Width;
    dgv.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Bottom);
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried removing dgv.Width and just use the anchor? Try anchoring to Top as well, and leave some space (which will remain fixed if your form is resized).

Comment: Im creating the DGV pro-grammatically so I think I need to set the width/height initially dont I? I tried removing the width and setting the anchors to include Top but it didn't help

Answer (score 1):

You can use following properties of DataGridView(dgv)to work

```
Anchor: Top,Left // dgv.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left
AutoSizeColumn: Fill // we can fill for all columns or else it is enough to fill the last column dgv..Columns[0].AutoSizeModeDataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
Dock: Fill // dgv.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
```

Just see the link [How to resize datagridview control when form resizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8183422/how-to-resize-datagridview-control-when-form-resizes)