# how to adjust txtbox width size according to gridview cell

Tags: c#, asp.net

is it possible to adjust Gridview Textbox width size automatically  accordingly Gridview cell size increase or decrease.

mean when grid cell width increase/decrease then text box (that are used on  header of gridview) width also auto increase/decrease.

your answer could be very helpful for me

thanks in advance

Comment: I guess, you are asking about responsive design. You can do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean for the column width to adjust to the cells contents? I am a little confused by “mean when grid cell width increase/decrease then text box (that are used on header of gridview) width also auto increase/decrease.”… The Cells header width will always grow with the column width. You can set each columns AutoSizeMode to AllCells… this will adjust the columns width to the width of the longest string in that column. The column width won’t change until the user hits the enter key. Hope this helps.

If you are looking for the grid to resize in a form i suggest the link below

[How to resize datagridview control when form resizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8183422/how-to-resize-datagridview-control-when-form-resizes)

Comment: yes of course i want to adjust textbox width according to column of grid